# Aggregation to fetch data from second collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to fetch data from second collection which's id is stored in first collection.
For example I have two collection collectionA and collectionB.

In collectionA i have this data:

```
{ 
    "aid" : "afa6ad98adf5adf", 
    "cid" : "collectionBid132"
},
{ 
    "aid" : "9sd5ds9ds5sd98", 
    "cid" : "collectionBid895"
},
{ 
    "aid" : "a98asd4f6a7afd", 
    "cid" : "collectionBid654"
}
```

In collectionB i have this data:

```
{ 
    "cid" : "collectionBid132", 
    "cData" : "cDataBid132"
},
{ 
    "cid" : "collectionBid895", 
    "cData" : "cDataBid895"
},
{ 
    "cid" : "collectionBid654", 
    "cData" : "cDataBid654"
}
```

Now i want to get value of `"cData" from collectionB where cid = "collectionBid895" in collectionA`.

how is it possible using aggregation ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$lookup` for this. The below query should work.

```
db.collectionA.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "collectionB",
          localField: "cid",
          foreignField: "cid",
          as: "collection_docs"
        }
   }
])
```

**Output:-**

The query output would be something like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57f25931dd4752c20947fcfc"),
    "aid" : "afa6ad98adf5adf",
    "cid" : "collectionBid132",
    "collection_docs" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57f2593bdd4752c20947fcff"),
            "cid" : "collectionBid132",
            "cData" : "cDataBid132"
        }
    ]
}
```